# How to distribute percentage of weight in given scenario

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

**Question** - I have table X which have random rows (it could be 10 rows, 100 rows and so on). Now I have percentage of weight lets suppose 33% 40% and 27%

and let name it

```
A=33%
B=40%
C=27%
```

so i have add one more column which have percentage of random row

```
****Row** |--Weight
row1  | A
row2  | C
row3 | B
.
.
.
row100 |B
```

Let suppose table have 1000 row then weight should be assign random like

```
A= 330
B=400
c=270
```

**What I Made-**
For below program I have to distribute segment on basis of value. For example, in below code I am iterating value to 1000, but it will distribute value like

```
A=300
B=400
C=300
```

instead of

```
A= 250, B=450 C=300. As  weight are 25%,45%,30%
```

It should be generic for any n number, for example, in this code n =1000 (iteration):

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //var t = Console.ReadLine().ToObservable();
        List<string> li = new List<string>();

        //t.Subscribe(m => Console.Write(m));
        for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
        {
            li.Add(GetSegment(i, "2.5,6.5,10.0", "A,B,C"));

        }
        Console.WriteLine("A Contains {0}",li.Count(x => x.Contains("A")));
        Console.WriteLine("B Contains {0}", li.Count(x => x.Contains("B")));
        Console.WriteLine("C Contains {0}", li.Count(x => x.Contains("C")));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static string GetSegment(long seed, string raw_segments, string segname)
    {

        var segmentsValue = raw_segments.Split(',').Select(entry => (double.Parse(entry))).ToArray();

        var segmentName = segname.Split(',').Select(entry => entry).ToArray();
        double theNumber = seed % 10;
        double index1 = segmentsValue.Where(entry => entry > theNumber).First();

        int index = Array.IndexOf(segmentsValue, index1);
        return segmentName[index].ToString();

    }
```

Comment: So where is the problem? Does the code you've written work for you? What is the expected output? What output are you getting? You've told us what you want the code to do, but you haven't described the problem (if any) with the code you have. Please add more information to clarify what you're asking for.

Comment: Hi Jim, There is no problem with code. Problem with code logic. As you can see i am passing percentage parameter as form of 25% 45% and 30% ( 2.5, 6.5 (which is addition of 2.5+4.) and 10.0 (rest)) . So according to logic it returns me 300,400,300 . And my requirement is to modify function so that it will return right percentage weight like 250, 450 and 300

Comment: I want it generic for any percentage weight

Comment: The problem is that `seed % 10` will always return a whole number in the range of 0 through 10. So 2.5 is greater than 0, 1, and 2. In every 10 numbers you see, `seed % 10` will be less than 2.5. Without knowing more about the distribution rules (i.e. does it matter how things are distributed as long as the percentages work?), it's impossible to say how you can fix your logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have some number of objects and you want to assign them randomly to three bins, based on some set distribution. For example, you want 33% in bin A, 40% in bin B, and the remaining 27% in bin C.

If your distribution doesn't have to be *exact* (i.e. given 1,000 items, bin A must contain exactly 330 items), then this is very easy: for each row you generate a random number between 0 and 1,000, and assign assign the row to the appropriate bin. For example:

```
int[] ranges = new int[]{330, 730, 1000};

var rnd = new Random();
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
{
    var r = rnd.Next(1000);
    if (r < ranges[0])
        Console.WriteLine("bin A");
    else if (r < ranges[1])
        Console.WriteLine("bin B");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("bin C");
}
```

*On average* over many runs, that will give you 33% in bin A, 40% in bin B, and 27% in bin C. But for any individual run the number of items in each bin will vary somewhat. For example, in one run you might end up with 327, 405, 268.

With a little work, you could adapt that method so that it doesn't over-assign any bin. Basically, when a bin fills up, remove it from the list of ranges. You'd need your list of ranges to be dynamic so that you could remove items and keep working, but it would allow you to exactly fill each bin.

If the number of items is small enough, you could create an array with the numbers from 0 to N, shuffle it, and assign the numbers that way. For example:

```
// builds an array of numbers from 0 to 999.
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).ToArray();
Shuffle(numbers);
```

Use the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) to shuffle the array. See https://gist.github.com/mikedugan/8249637 (among many others) for an implementation.

You now have an array containing the numbers from 0 to 999 in random order. This is like pre-assigning a unique random number to each of your records. So when you go through your list of records you look up its corresponding random number in the numbers array. For example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
{
    var value = numbers[i];
    char bin;
    if (value < 330) bin = 'A';
    else if (value < 730) bin = 'B';
    else bin = 'C';

    Console.WriteLine("Record {0} goes to bin {1}", i, bin);
}
```

Comment: What if row have 200 records?  how this condition work                          if (value < 330) bin = 'A';
    else if (value < 730) bin = 'B';
    else bin = 'C';

Comment: @asthanarht: Obviously, you change the numbers (in the array I showed at the top) to reflect 33%, 40%, and 27% of the total number of items. I assumed that you understood that I was showing *examples*, and that you'd have to extrapolate how to make them more generic.

Comment: Thanks you so much , I modified code (took logic from you) and its working perfectly.

Comment: @asthanarht: If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted. Just click the check mark next to the answer on the left.